# autocmd calling function isn't triggered

Tags: autocmd, functions

The following ftdetect-file doesn't work as expected:

```
augroup dummy
  au!
  au BufRead bla* setf dummy
  au BufRead bla* call s:detect_ft()
augroup END

echom 'one'

function! s:detect_ft() abort
  echom 'two'
endfunction
```

It always displays only `one`, regardless of the order of the two autocmds. The filetype `dummy` is always correctly assigned, but the function `s:detect_ft()` is never triggered.

Why? I don't see any reason this should not work?

Comment: Yes, I am. I noticed that this does not work, because _the real logic_ wasn't executed. I then reduced it to this simple test case to check it. I deliberately used echom to be able to see it in the `:messages` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filetype is probably being overwritten by the built-in autocommands. You probably need to include `BufEnter` and `BufNewFile`:

```
augroup dummy
  au!
  au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter bla* setf dummy
  au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter bla* call s:detect_ft()
augroup END

echom 'one'

function! s:detect_ft() abort
  echom 'two'
endfunction
```

Comment: I thought so, too. But no other file type is assigned. Also that would mean _both_ autocmd would not trigger. But the one setting `setf dummy` actually _is_ triggered.

Comment: I just gave it a try and it seems to be working fine. Filetype correctly set as `dummy` and `detect_ft` function called.

Comment: I will try it out when I am back at a computer.

Comment: So, I checked now. With your changes it works. Now, the next question is: why? Or better: Why does it not work with only BufRead? Remember: There is a difference, There first autocmd is executed in any case, the second only if BufNewFile and BufEnter are added..

Comment: which autocommand is executed first? If you're referring to `setf dummy`, only with `BufRead`, that's not being executed either

Comment: I am totally lost now. Yes, I meant the `setf dummy`. Today I double checked again and can't understand it. With the example code snippet above, it behaves as you said: No autocmd is triggered. But in my actual plugin code it does work. _Both_ autocmds are fired now. Even the one that calls the funtion (and previously did not, which is why I was writing this question). I give up now. Don't try to understand. Catching all 3 events seems to avoid this problem, so that is the way to go for me.

Comment: Well, I don't know understand why it works in your plugin, but not in your vimrc. By the way, on second thoughts, maybe you don't need `BufEnter` because that will make the function run twice. `BufRead,BufNewFile` should be enough.